# Pinescript multiple 'alert.freq_once_per_bar' alerts on a single bar

Tags: pine-script, alert, trading, pine-script-v5

I've recently been having some issues regarding Pinescripts alert() functions, specifically regarding the 'freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar' aspect of the alerts. I have been receiving duplicate alerts even when trying to restrict the alerts to one per bar. I have attached a screenshot that may explain a little better - the yellow dots on the chart indicate where the stop loss for the strategy is, and once price has crossed the strategy should fire an 'Exit' alert - which is does successfully. However just a few moments later another 'Exit' alert is fired. What is even stranger is when going to a lower timeframe it's not even due to price crossing beneath the stop, crossing above it and then crossing below again, the second alert seemingly fires randomly. This is especially annoying as these alerts are the basis of my automated trading and are skewing returns.

This example is just one of multiple that have occurred over the past few weeks - with seemingly no pattern to link them together. They have occurred on both long/short entry/exit alerts, sometimes firing 3/4 alerts per bar.

I have included a small snippet of the code for you to see. I have experimented with the strategy alerts/order fill alerts but have had no success with them at all. Therefore the alert logic is all calculated using originally made logic within v5 Pine for determining position size and executing alerts. The code never has any issue with missing alerts, or firing duplicates frequently - the first alert is always correct and seemingly 1% - 5% of the time a duplicate or even multiple duplicates randomly get through too. I have even attempted adding multiple different 'limiters' that try and only allow one alert per bar but so far none have really made any difference. Changing the alerts to 'alert.freq_once_per_bar_close' would also not suffice as the strategy is based on intra-bar limit orders.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and advice on how to genuinely limit alerts to one per bar! If more info is required please get in touch.

Thanks in advance.

[Duplicate Alert Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BqNR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am no big programmer but I think this is the expected behaviour as you can have multiple crosses up and down while the bar is still live if you are using once per bar ( instead of once per bar close ).

I would suggest using a counter on the alert with a loop so if it triggers the first time , the counter is increased and this should then cause the loop to abort due to condition you set... I think this may work... havent tried it.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I actually do have something like this in place within my code:
`code`

    var long_exit_index = bar_index
    var long_exit_triggered = false
    if long_exit_trigger and not long_exit_trigger[1] and (bar_index != long_exit_index)
        if not long_exit_triggered
            alert(message = 'Long Exit', freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)
            long_exit_index := bar_index
            long_exit_triggered := true
    else
        long_exit_triggered := false

`code`

And the error persists unfortunately.

Comment: I actually have had the same code and configuration running 3 times for testing and have got duplicates on only one different alert at a time on multiple instances - seemingly making this issue an almost randomly occurring backend issue within TradingView.